# Populating a cell with a string in a datagrid view based on if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach, datagridview

I have a datagridview which displays values in an array. I would like the 5th column to show a string based on the data in the previous columns. I have a foreach loop as you can see but column 5 is still appearing blank. All help appreciated.

```
 try
     {
     if (File.Exists("competitorDetailsFile.txt")) //if this file exists
     {
     string[] detailsArray = File.ReadLines("competitorDetailsFile.txt") .ToArray();
   //write data to array
     double time = 0;
     double time1 = 0;


   for (int number = 0; number < detailsArray.Length;number++)
      {
       string[] detailsArray2 = detailsArray[number].Split('~'); 

 //split on tilda

    time1 = Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[3]) + 
            Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[4]) + 
            Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[5]) + 
            Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[6]) + 
            Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[7]);
    time = time1 / 5;
    int score = Convert.ToInt32(detailsArray2[8]);


     //time is equal to the average of the ski times 

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(detailsArray2[0], 
    Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[1]), 
    Convert.ToInt32(detailsArray2[8]), 
    time);

{
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
       {
           foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
           {
             if (time > 100)
           {
             row.Cells[5].Value = "LOW";
           }
             else if (time < 100)
           {
             row.Cells[5].Value = "HIGH";
           }

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting of your code? It's hard to read right now!

Comment: Apologies. Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're adding a fifth column (so can't reference it later) and the foreach loops seem unnecessary...  Try

```
string score = 
   time > 200
      ? "LOWEST"
      : time > 100
         ? "LOW"
         : time > 50
            ? "MEDIUM"
            : "HIGH";

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(detailsArray2[0], Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[1]), Convert.ToInt32(detailsArray2[8]), time, score);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is great! Is there a way that I can put 3 options, instead of just LOW and HIGH?

Comment: You can cascade the ternary, I've edited my answer to reflect this.